# Why do my CLLocation functions stop working when I insert them into an action button?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

So I've been using this tutorial, http://www.veasoftware.com/tutorials/2014/10/18/xcode-6-tutorial-ios-8-current-location-in-swift, to learn how to get some basic location information using the CLLocation class. I got it to successfully run when I declare the delegates and other methods INSIDE the viewDidLoad. Yay!

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

class ProfileScreenViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate    {

let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

@IBOutlet var userInfoLabel: UILabel!
var currentUser = PFUser.currentUser()!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated:true);

        }




override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


@IBAction func testUserInfoButton(sender: UIButton) {
    PFUser.logOut()
    var currentUser = PFUser.currentUser()
    self.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated:true);
    self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
}

@IBAction func getLocationButton(sender: UIButton) {
    self.locationManager.delegate = self
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didFailWithError error: NSError!) {
        println("error " + error.localizedDescription)
    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {
        CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(manager.location, completionHandler: { (placemarks, error) -> Void in

            if error != nil {
                println("error" + error.localizedDescription)
            }

            if placemarks.count > 0 {
                let pm = placemarks[0] as CLPlacemark
                self.displayLocationInfo(pm)
            } else {
                println("Error " + error.localizedDescription)
            }
        })
    }

    func displayLocationInfo(placemark: CLPlacemark){
        locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
        println(placemark.locality)
        println(placemark.postalCode)
        println(placemark.administrativeArea)
        println(placemark.country)
    }



}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SLPgu.jpg

However! When I try and move everything to a button action, everything falls apart. The code is the same, and I have no idea how to fix this. I tried re-typing over and over again. The errors keep telling me things like, "definition conflicts with previous value", or such and such view controller does not have a member name x. I even went to another tutorial, on another site, who essentially wrote the same code but into a button (like exactly what I'm trying to do). But they got it to work.

After fiddling around, I got it down to 3 errors. But the frustrating thing is, it is still the exact same code that I got working before... I feel like I'm missing something here when I transfer code within a button, but I'm still a bit new to Swift/Xcode.

As requested, WORKING code, without errors:

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

class ProfileScreenViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

@IBOutlet var userInfoLabel: UILabel!
var currentUser = PFUser.currentUser()!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated:true);

    self.locationManager.delegate = self
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didFailWithError error: NSError!) {
    println("error " + error.localizedDescription)
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {
    CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(manager.location, completionHandler: { (placemarks, error) -> Void in

        if error != nil {
            println("error" + error.localizedDescription)
        }

        if placemarks.count > 0 {
            let pm = placemarks[0] as CLPlacemark
            self.displayLocationInfo(pm)
        } else {
            println("Error " + error.localizedDescription)
        }
    })
}

func displayLocationInfo(placemark: CLPlacemark){
        locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
        println(placemark.locality)
        println(placemark.postalCode)
        println(placemark.administrativeArea)
        println(placemark.country)
}
```

Anyways, I thank you if you can take a look at the code, or perhaps have encountered something like this. It's such a small thing, but after 4 hours, I had to seek help.

Sorry I had to link out my images... Stackoverflow didn't let me post images... Very unhelpful...

Comment: What are the errors?  Can you post the code?

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/pI1tP

Comment: You have 2 functions with the same name.  Also, can you please copy/paste code and errors into your question instead of posting screenshots?

Comment: You cannot declare function inside a function. Move your functions outside of button action.

Comment: Really? This tutorial told me I could write functions inside a function (button). http://rshankar.com/get-your-current-address-in-swift/

Also, I've successfully posted functions inside of buttons, such as registering users in. Is there a reason for CLLocation methods not allowing that?

Answer (score 0):

Whoops. Apparently, you can't define functions inside an action... Strangely enough I've done it already somewhere else in my code.

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

class ProfileScreenViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

@IBOutlet var userInfoLabel: UILabel!
var currentUser = PFUser.currentUser()!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated:true);

        }

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didFailWithError error: NSError!) {
    println("error " + error.localizedDescription)
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {
    CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(manager.location, completionHandler: { (placemarks, error) -> Void in

        if error != nil {
            println("error" + error.localizedDescription)
        }

        if placemarks.count > 0 {
            let pm = placemarks[0] as CLPlacemark
            self.displayLocationInfo(pm)
        } else {
            println("Error " + error.localizedDescription)
        }
    })
}

func displayLocationInfo(placemark: CLPlacemark){
        locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
        println(placemark.locality)
        println(placemark.postalCode)
        println(placemark.administrativeArea)
        println(placemark.country)
}




override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


@IBAction func testUserInfoButton(sender: UIButton) {
    PFUser.logOut()
    var currentUser = PFUser.currentUser()
    self.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated:true);
    self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
}

@IBAction func getLocationButton(sender: UIButton) {
    self.locationManager.delegate = self
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Had similar problems using Swift 2, I had to change :-

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {
    CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(manager.location, completionHandler: { (placemarks, error) -> Void in
```

to

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(manager.location!, completionHandler: {(placemarks, error)->Void in
```

which stops one of your errors.